# Blender Cycles 2.78a Scene/Image renders out with grainy pixels everywhere

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am a somewhat new user to blender and I have recently dived headfirst into cycles. I have watched a lot of tutorials on how to fix this but none of them have brought me the answer I need. I am using blender 2.78a and am trying to make a cool scene of a room but no matter what I do I cant seem to get rid of all the grain that is in the picture. There Is grain behind the couch and grain all around my picture. if you need to know I have a sun in the scene as well. Also most of the texture I have made are glass but have been roughed out and the IQR set to around 3. I have tried to use the clamp stuff under the sampling tap but don't really know how to use it properly. For my lighting I have used cubes and circles but I heard that doing that can cause problems. I also have the multiple importance turned off on everything.

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE because I have done every single thing in the post that was linked to me and it didn't change a thing.
  [image: Room/Scene]

Comment: you need to increase the  number of samples

Comment: I'd say increase your samples to 1000 or more and see if that helps.

Comment: 248 samples is not a lot.

Comment: I Figured it out needed to turn on square sampling.